# HATEOAS with multiple pages

Tags: hateoas

Is there a rule to define a sequential list of links using HATEOAS?

It is easy to add self, next and previous links to a HATEOAS-based response. Below is a sample response:

```
{ 
  links : [{
            rel : "next",
            href : "http://localhost:8080/persons?page=1&size=20"
          }], 
  content : [{
     id: "",
     name: "",
     lastname: "",
     age: 0
  }],
  pageMetadata : { 
    size : 20, 
    totalElements : 30, 
    totalPages : 2, 
    number : 0
  } 
};
```

So, pagination with next and previous links is not difficult but I couldn't figure out how it is possible to access for example 10th page directly, for example using a select element (let's assume there are more than 10 pages). Should I add all the links to the response as, for example, page1, page2, page3, etc? Of course I know the format of the request so I could just create the appropriate query but that seems kind of wrong because the whole point seems to be not relying on the actual link of the service. I am not an expert on this issue and I couldn't find an answer in this site or from Google.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common solution is to use [URI templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570). Specifically, section 3.2.8 regarding [Form-Style Query Expansion](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-3.2.8).

Assuming both `page` and `size` are optional, you would construct your link URI template as `localhost:8080/persons{?page,size}`.

URI templates do not define which values are acceptable; there's no mechanism for restricting `page` or `size` to numeric values. As such, you should include this template in addition to your existing next/prev links. I'm not exactly sure which link relation best describes such a resource, but "collection" doesn't seem too far off.

In order to use URI templates, you'll need a library in whichever languages will be producing/consuming the template. A quick search produced a [list of libraries](https://code.google.com/p/uri-templates/wiki/Implementations) in various languages which you may find helpful.

Lastly, depending on your hypermedia format you may need to specify a templated URI as such. For example, HAL+JSON uses a boolean `templated` property.

```
{
    "_links": {
        "collection": {
            "href":      "/persons{?page,size}",
            "templated": true
        }
    }
}
```